# Make dynamic celery timeout between tasks

Tags: python, celery

I have a service which I could connect not more often then 1 time per 25 seconds, so I make celery task runs every 30 seconds, but sometimes one task lasts more then 5 seconds and I've got ban from server for 5 minutes. Is there any way to postpone task if previous similar task ends less then 25 seconds ago?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place to use celery's [rate limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=rate%20limit#Task.rate_limit) feature, keep in mind that if you have multiple workers you will also need to restrict this task to a particular queue since rate limits in this context are a per-worker basis

```
@shared_task(rate_limit = "2/m")
def mytask(a, b):
    return a + b
```